# WARNING ZODB.blob ... has insecure mode setting

Tags: plone

Is "WARNING ZODB.blob ... has insecure mode setting" after buildout, a problem?
Is there a guide to what the permissions should be, if this is a permissions issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an identified bug. A solution has been reported at [bugs.launchpad.com](https://bugs.launchpad.net/karl3/+bug/689506)